# XSLT document function with relative URI to allow for http or https

Tags: c#, xslt

This is a two part question:

**1)** I am using the XSLT document function to grab XML from a REST endpoint during a transformation. This works fine if I explicitly add the scheme to the uri, i.e., `document('http://...')`. However, the final release of the site I'm working on may or may not be accessed securely (https). To compensate for this, is it possible to use a relative URI, i.e., `document('//...')` in the XSLT document function as you would for other resources like images, etc.?

I am attempting to do this with the native .NET `XsltCompiledTransform` and receiving the following error: `"Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed."` Is this a limitation in .NET and achievable with Saxon or another 2.0 processor or is it just not possible?

**UPDATE**

The exception being thrown is an `XsltTransformException` with an inner `UriFormatException` with the following stack traces:

```
at System.Xml.Xsl.Runtime.XmlQueryContext.GetDataSource(String uriRelative, String uriBase)
at <xsl:template match="Nomination">(XmlQueryRuntime {urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt-debug}runtime, XPathNavigator {urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt-debug}current)
at <xsl:template match="/">(XmlQueryRuntime {urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt-debug}runtime, XPathNavigator {urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt-debug}current)
at Root(XmlQueryRuntime {urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt-debug}runtime)
at Execute(XmlQueryRuntime {urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt-debug}runtime)
at System.Xml.Xsl.XmlILCommand.Execute(Object defaultDocument, XmlResolver dataSources, XsltArgumentList argumentList, XmlSequenceWriter results)
at System.Xml.Xsl.XmlILCommand.Execute(Object defaultDocument, XmlResolver dataSources, XsltArgumentList argumentList, XmlWriter writer)
at System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform.Transform(IXPathNavigable input, XsltArgumentList arguments, XmlWriter results, XmlResolver documentResolver)
at System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform.Transform(IXPathNavigable input, XsltArgumentList arguments, XmlWriter results)
at AAFC.Web.XsltView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer)
```

Inner stack trace:

```
at System.Uri.CreateThis(String uri, Boolean dontEscape, UriKind uriKind)
at System.Uri.CreateUri(Uri baseUri, String relativeUri, Boolean dontEscape)
at System.Uri..ctor(Uri baseUri, String relativeUri)
at System.Xml.XmlResolver.ResolveUri(Uri baseUri, String relativeUri)
at System.Xml.XmlUrlResolver.ResolveUri(Uri baseUri, String relativeUri)
at System.Xml.Xsl.Runtime.XmlQueryContext.GetDataSource(String uriRelative, String uriBase)
```

**2)** My concern is (and I have not tested this so it may be moot), is that if the final site is accessed securely (https) and the transform is referencing an insecure REST endpoint (http) that problems may arise. Is this a valid concern, or will the transformation happen regardless?

Comment: Can you show the stack trace?

Comment: @Max Toro added the stack trace(s) as requested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested on Powershell and the URI resolution works fine:

```
PS C:\> $u = new-object Uri (new-object Uri "https://a.com"), "//b.com/"
PS C:\> $u.AbsoluteUri
https://b.com/
```

If you are using a relative URI as argument to the document function then that is resolved using the static base URI of the stylesheet module, which can be customized by using the [Load overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms163424) that accepts an [XmlReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.xml.xmlreader) instance, and using one of the [Create overloads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.xml.xmlreader.create) that accept a baseUri parameter.

Comment: This seems to be working and I will accept as the answer after more testing, but I do have one additional question: if I set the base URI to `https://...` but the XSLT is being executed within an `http://...` context, what will be honored, the stylesheet base URI or the scheme of the website it's being executed in?

Comment: @crazyarabian: The XSLT processor knows nothing about 'the scheme of the website it's being executed in'.

Comment: Thanks for your help, you pointed me in the direction I needed to go and I think I have it working now. In the Load overload, I am able to use `viewContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.Scheme` as the base URI which handles the http/https scenarios.

Comment: @crazyarabian: Since the base URI is used to resolve relative includes and imports in XSLT I recommend you pass that information in a parameter, e.g. `document(concat($currentScheme, '//...'))`.